# sql - where clause NULL

Tags: sql

I have the following in my where clause

```
    WHERE st.State =  @St
```

In this case @St is NULL. If st.State is also NULL this will not return TRUE.
How do I do my where clause in this case?

I was thinking of

```
    WHERE st.State =  @St AND @St IS NULL
```

but not sure if that will buy me much.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
WHERE ( @St IS NULL AND st.State IS NULL ) OR ( @St = st.State)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE st.State = @St OR (@St IS NULL AND st.State IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 WHERE (st.State = @St or (st.State is NULL and @St is NULL))
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to do different things on different databases, but one general approach is

```
WHERE st.State = @St OR (@St is NULL and st.State is NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what system you're working on, but I'm fond of IsNull on SQL Server systems:

```
WHERE (IsNull(st.State,'none')=IsNull(@St,'none')
```

Answer (score 0):

check this. this will work.

ISNULL(st.State,'') = ISNULL(@St,'')

Answer (score 0):

```
  select column1 from Table1
  where (@param is null and column2 is null)
  or (column2 = @param)
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of why this works.